# rtabmap 0.21.3 - Rtabmap: Parameter "GridGlobal/FullUpdate" doesn't exist anymore!

Tags: ros, ros-noetic, rtabmap, rtabmap-ros

recently I updated my system with "sudo apt update" and "sudo apt upgrade" and rtabmap passed to 0.21.3 version but now I am having trouble launching rtabmap ( "rosrun rtabmap_slam rtabmap " ).
I have Ubuntu 20.04 and the error everytime I try to launch this node I get "Rtabmap: Parameter "GridGlobal/FullUpdate" doesn't exist anymore!"

First time I saw this error it was through a launch file, later I try to run rtabmap with rosrun and I noticed that it is an error with the package and not with the launch file.

Following a snippet of the launch file:

```
<node  if="$(arg mapping)" name="rtabmap" pkg="rtabmap_slam" type="rtabmap" output="screen" args="--delete_db_on_start image_transport:=compressed">
    <!-- if subscribe stereo -->
    <remap from="left/image_rect"       to="/zed2/left/image_rect_color"/>
    <remap from="right/image_rect"      to="/zed2/right/image_rect_color"/>
    <remap from="left/camera_info"      to="/zed2/left/camera_info"/>
    
    <remap from="right/camera_info"     to="/zed2/right/camera_info"/>

    <remap from="odom" to="/odom"/>  

    <!-- if subscribe depth -->
    <remap from="rgb/image"         to="/zed2/left/image_rect_color"/>
    <remap from="depth/image"       to="/zed2/depth/depth_registered"/>
    <remap from="rgb/camera_info"   to="/zed2/left/camera_info"/>

    <param name="queue_size" type="int" value="50"/>

    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find my_package)/config/rtabmap_params.yaml" />

  </node>
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly